# FileInputStream fails on properties file

Tags: java

This properties file in `PROJECT/resources/properties.properties` can be read and show its content with:

```
public void showFileContent(String fileName){

    File file = new File (fileName);
    FileInputStream input = null;

    if(file.exists()){
        int content;
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            while ((content = input.read()) != -1) {
                System.out.print((char) content);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }       
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error : properties File "  + fileName + " not found");
    }
}
```

But it fails with a null pointer exception at properties.load with that code

```
public Properties getProperties(String fileName, Properties properties){

    File file = new File (fileName);
    InputStream input = null;

    if(file.exists()){
        try {
            input = new FileInputStream(fileName);
            properties.load(input);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (input != null) {
                try {
                    input.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Error : properties File "  + fileName + " not found");
    }
    return properties;
}
```

even when input is set to

```
input = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName)
```

anyone knows why that can be for a properties text file at the same path for both methods ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the first code snippet works, it seems `properties` is passed as null to the `getProperties()` method, resulting in `NullPointerException`.

Ideally, we shouldn't be passing the `properties` at all. We just need to create a new `object` and return it.

Comment: actually you are right. I just don't understand why I can't extend properties with new properties, thought it's an endless hashtable !?
actually would like to seperate properties in files like web.properties, db properties etc.

Comment: We don't need to extend the properties. We can just call `putAll` method on any of the existing properties object to add new properties (another object). E.g. `Properties p = new Properties(); p.putAll(p1);`